# Fade in content from specific post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get an effect like on [this site](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/) so that when I click a div, jquery takes the id of the current clicked div and stores it in a variable.

```
$(function (){ 
    $('.project-wrapper').click(function() { 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',                    
            url:'wp-content/themes/MartinFjeldUpdated/header.php',   
            dataType : 'HTML',         
            data:{"id" : id},             
            success: function(rs)
            {
                $(".display-video-image-graphic-fade").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });  
    }); 
});
```

Then I would like to get that variable to a php variable so that is automatically  change the content I want to fade in simply by clicking the thumbnail of a post.

```
<?php
    $paged = $_post['id'];
    $args= array(
        'id' => $paged,
    );

    query_posts($args);; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" class="display-video-image-graphic-fade">
        <div class="display-outer-frame">
            <div class="display-middle-frame">
                <div class="video-frame">
                    <div id="slider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h3 class="title-head"> <?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                    <div class="inliner back-forth">
                        <div id="left" class="arrows">
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/MartinFjeldUpdated/images/left.pdf">
                        </div>
                        <div id="right" class="arrows">
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/MartinFjeldUpdated/images/right.pdf">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inliner out-cross">
                        <div class="cross">
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/MartinFjeldUpdated/images/cross.pdf">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
```

Somehow it does not work.. I am a real amateur in this, so if you need more explaining, please let me know and I'll try my best.
 Thanks.

Comment: Add $("#"+id).html(rs); in success

Comment: What's not working ? Jquery fadeIn or data ? If jQuery fadeIn is not working, then try 
$(".display-video-image-graphic-fade").slideDown();

Comment: @SunilPachlangia when I do that, the whole html page loads inside of the div... I don't think that is the right way but you're onto something I think!

Comment: @BhupenderKeswani it's the data that doesn't return the right value

Comment: @Snik1 I would suggest you to debug code by printing post id in output. Also few rectifications "$_POST" (caps), instead of using "/wp-content/themes/MartinFjeldUpdated/images/cross.pdf"  use <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/cross.pdf (also it should be png or gif, not pdf)